# Uniform Convergence Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

If $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a_k}x^k$ has a interval of convergence $(-1, 1)$, and $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a_k}x^k $, for $x\in[0,1)$, then the series does not converge uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1)$.

I'm trying to either come up with a proof for this statement.

Comment: Does series converge for $x=1$?

Comment: $a_k=(-1)^k$ seems to work as a counterexample.

Comment: @zkutch No, since the interval of convergence for the series is only $(-1, 1)$, not $(-1, 1]$.

Comment: If, so, then you can consider $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$ which is not uniformly converged on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @zkutch That's just one example. The point is to show the series never converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1)$ or to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We are given $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ diverges at $x=1.$ I.e., $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ diverges. This implies the partial sums of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ do not form a Cauchy sequence. Perhaps this implies the partial sums of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ are not uniformly Cauchy on $[0,1)?$